# Dynamically change Apache Camel file options

Tags: file, dynamic, parameters, apache-camel

I wish to change the file (or ftp) Camel component behaviour according to some value, for intance the value of a header.
I see in the Camel File documentation I can dynamically change the "CamelFilename" header, but ca we do the same with other options such as "fileexist" ?

My goal is to use only 1 FTP producer to write all files, some of them can be overriden and the others can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Camel's `.toD(..)`

More info: http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html#MessageEndpoint-DynamicTo